# ATOMで作成したPowerShell(ps1)が文字化けする

Tags: atom-editor, powershell

ATOMエディターで以下のスクリプトを書きました
以下がスクリプトの内容です

```
Write-Host "ハロー"
```

PowerShellから実行すると文字化けします。

```
HelloWorld.ps1
> 繝上Ο繝ｼ
```

ATOMではUTF-8を使っています。これは変えたくないのですが
拡張子がps1の場合のみ Shift-JIS で保存するような機能はATOMにありますか？

または、PowerShellの設定を変える事で文字化けしなくなるように
出来ますでしょうか？

> PowerShell version
>   Name                           Value
>   ----                           -----
>   PSVersion                      5.1.15063.674
>   PSEdition                      Desktop
>   PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
>   BuildVersion                   10.0.15063.674
>   CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
>   WSManStackVersion              3.0
>   PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
>   SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
>
> ATOM Vetsion
>   1.21.1

Comment: 試してみた所UTF-8で問題なく動作しました。 検索してみたところ、この[記事](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ja-JP/1d5bf04b-9b0a-4188-9328-a9eca3d897e8/powershellps1psm?forum=powershellja) でもShift-JISとUTF-8で実行可能らしいですが・・

Comment: ありがとうございます。ただAtomがBOM無しUTF-8なので駄目なのでしょうか。やはり文字化けしてしまいます。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Atom インストールして確かめましたが UTF-8 保存するとBOMが付かないので、 `powershell` インタプリタがレガシーエンコーディングで読んで文字化けしますね。
ISE じゃなくてどうしても Atom で ps1 書きたいなら、下記のような方法があるでしょう。

- BOM付きUTF-8 を扱えるよう Atom に要望を出す → https://discuss.atom.io/
- BOM無しUTF-8 を扱えるよう PowerShell に要望を出す → https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell
- [unicode-input](https://atom.io/packages/unicode-input) を使いファイルの先頭に BOM (U+FEFF) を入力する。
  入力しても文字は見えません。カーソルを左や右に移動させて幅ゼロの文字があることを確かめてください。
- [language-powershell](https://atom.io/packages/language-powershell) 使っているなら `config.cson` に

  ```
  ".source.powershell":
    core:
      fileEncoding: "shiftjis"
  ```

  と付け足す。
  カスタマイズについて詳しくは http://flight-manual.atom.io/using-atom/sections/basic-customization を見てください。新規ファイルのときは名前を付けて保存する前に、画面右下の Plain Text ってなっているのを PowerShell にしておかないと、utf8（デフォルトエンコーディング）で保存してしまい（しかも shiftjis で読み直して文字化けし）ます。

Comment: language-powershellを使っていたので、そちらで試して文字化けが解消されました。Atomインストールまでして確かめていただいたようで、ありがとうございます！おかげで解決しました。

Comment: タイムリーなことに最新の [Windows 10のInsider PreviewでシステムロケールをUTF-8にするオプションが追加されました](https://srad.jp/story/17/11/14/0640253/)！ 一応 試したところ BOM無しUTF-8 で保存された HelloWorld.ps1 も文字化けせずメッセージ表示されました (PSVersion 5.1.17035.1000, BuildVersion 10.0.17035.1000)。ベータ版なので今 使うのは自己責任になってしまいますが、そのうちこの設定がリリース版でも使えるようになるでしょう。